# How do you say "you can do this or that"?

Tags: grammar

I'm having trouble figuring out how to suggest two different scenarios. The question on my homework was "What can you do with $300?" I am looking to say something along the lines of "You could buy A, or you could buy B", as in, you wouldn't be able to buy both. So far, I've seen あるいは, それとも, and どっち, but I don't know if these are usable in this context. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a danger that your question will be seen as a translation request and closed since you have not provided an attempt at translating. I have just asked a related question here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/75221/how-to-express-alternative-options-where-the-options-use-different-verbs

Comment: Do you have to explicitly tell "either...or"?

Answer (score 0):

If you are applying the same verb to both actions, as in your question, then you can just join the objects together with か, e.g.

> AかBを買えます。
>   You can buy A or B.

If you want to use different verbs e.g. "You can buy a cat or deposit your money in the bank" then I'm not sure I know how to do this. I have asked a [separate question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/75221/how-to-express-alternative-options-where-the-options-use-different-verbs).