# How to express alternative options where the options use different verbs

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, particle-か

I was about to answer [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/75219/how-do-you-say-you-can-do-this-or-that#75219) when I realised I had a problem.

If I want to say "Please do A or B" where the actions involve different verbs then, hopefully:

> 本を買うのに店に行く**か**インターネットを使う**かどちらか**してください。
>   Please either go to the shop or use the internet to buy the book.

is a grammatical -- and hopefully natural -- sentence.

So if I wanted to say "You can do A or B" it seems like a natural extension to write:

> 本を買うのに店に行くかインターネットを使うかどちらか出来ます。
>   To buy a book you can either go to a shop or use the internet.

But the internet has a disturbing lack of text that contains どちらか出来ます, so I'm guessing that this is, at best, unnatural and maybe ungrammatical too.

If it is unnatural what is the correct way to express that you have the ability to do one thing or another thing (but not necessarily both)?

Comment: Maybe it would make sense if you gave a more natural example sentence and the situations you might use it in.

Comment: Down vote? Wow, it's getting tough round here.  I don't think it takes too much imagination to make this into a valid sentence. Suppose I have a limited amount of time, therefore I can watch a film or read a book, but not both (it's a short book, but a long film). I can go to the gym or do my shopping. I can pay by direct debit or write a cheque. I can catch a bus or drive my car. The list of applicable sentences is endless.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I think your example definitely makes it harder to talk productively on the subject.

Comment: @Ringil Fair enough. I've edited to something which is hopefully more sensible.

Comment: In your example we actually don't use any verb in the option phrase.

Comment: @broccoliforest Thanks for the response. Sadly, I don't understand. Which part are you calling the 'option phrase'? Could you give an example please?

Comment: @user3856370 I think the commonest way to say it is 本は書店かインターネットで買えます. And I don't see the necessity to really use an exclusive condition in that situation?

Comment: @broccoliforest Sorry for not being able to explain myself clearly. I'm not interested in the particular sentence I just used, but the general construction. Here's another example "In my work break I can either **eat** my sandwiches **or go** to a cafe". I'm hoping we can't reduce this example to single verb. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @user3856370 Do you still need this question answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For "Please do A or B", I think you can use ～するか～してください, as in:

> 「更新をスタートするにはシャットダウンする**か**再起動**してください**。」(Windows)
> 「事前に窓口でお求めいただく**か**、インターネット予約をご利用**ください**。」(バス会社)
> 「このままお待ちいただく**か**しばらく経ってからおかけ直し**ください**。」(電話が混んでるときの音声メッセージ)

Likewise, for "You can do A or B", I think you can use 「～するか～することができます」, as in:

> "In my work break I can either eat my sandwiches or go to a cafe."
> 「休み時間は、サンドイッチを食べる**か**、カフェに行く**ことができます**。」
> "I can watch a film or read a book (it's a short book, but a long film)."
> 「映画を(一本)観る**か**、(短い)本を(一冊)読む**ことができます**。」

I think you can also use 「～してもいいし～してもいいです」, as in:

> "You can catch a bus or drive your car."
> 「バスに乗っ**てもいいし**、車で行っ**てもいいです**。」
> "You can buy a car or deposit your money in the bank."
> 「車を買っ**てもいいし**、(**または/あるいは/何も買わないで**)貯金し**てもいいです**よ。」

Answer (score 2):

それとも is also another possibility.

Comment: Your answer would be more complete if you gave an example or two.